# Does the F-16's neutral stability also extend to the negative-G flight regime?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, pilot-technique, f-16

If an F-16 pilot pushes the stick forward hard enough to send the aircraft into negative-G flight, does the jet tend to accentuate the new flightpath, requiring the pilot to counter that, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F-16 is unstable at low speeds, and stable at higher Mach numbers. It has a flight control computer though, which stabilizes the aircraft using the feedback from pitch rate (so from the view of the pilot an F-16 acts similarly as a stable aircraft). This applies to both positive and negative attitude disturbances, so for both + and - G loads perceived by the pilot.

Comment: Thanks ,this instability translate into the quick response in pitch up and down or only up ,this is my question ?Your answer  is accepted.

Comment: The stability of the aircraft depends one the derivatives of state variables (velocities and rates). In a normal flight regime (not near stall) these are continuous functions, so the (in)stability will work "both ways". Here you can learn more about the flight dynamics of the F-16: http://home.sch.bme.hu/~xtrykyx/diplomaterv/Egyeb/F16Manual.pdf

Comment: Thank you  for your time.